# SciKit-Learn: Grid Search CV Recording Times?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm doing some basic machine learning and want to do grid search for XGBoost (to find the best hyperparameters).  Here's what I'm doing:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import xgboost as xgb

pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', xgb.XGBRegressor(silent=False))])
parameters = {
'clf__n_estimators': (500, 1000), 
    'clf__learning_rate': (0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
    'clf__max_depth': (10, 20, 30)
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1,verbose=2, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

So I start getting output in my Jupyter notebook as follows:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 18 candidates, totalling 54 fits
[CV] clf__max_depth=10, clf__learning_rate=0.01, clf__n_estimators=500
```

All seems good but then it goes through all of the combinations and doesn't terminate.  Instead, it starts printing the following:

```
[CV]  clf__max_depth=10, clf__learning_rate=0.01, clf__n_estimators=500 -119.5min
[CV]  clf__max_depth=10, clf__learning_rate=0.01, clf__n_estimators=500 -119.8min
```

What does this mean?  I was expecting grid search to perform 54 fits and be done but it seems to be doing other stuff afterward?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, its not doing any other stuff as you mentioned. The cause here is n_jobs = -1. Try changing that to n_jobs=1 and it will end successfully after `fit()`. I dont know why it doesnt work with multi-threading. Maybe some issue of xgboost (even though multi-threading version of xgboost is installed).

Comment: This [issue at xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/512) and [this at scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6627) discuss this in more detail.